# Javascript: Print (to printer...) from var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, printing

I have something like this on a `$.ajax()` success function:

```
var popup = window.open('',titulo,"menubar=0,location=0,height=500,width=800");
popup.document.write(response);
popup.print();
```

My problem is that some browsers block popups, and my only need is to print.
I've found [jqPrint](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint), it is a jQuery plugin that prints from elements using an `iframe`.

And I do not want to load another plugin... :/

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you are going to get a much better option than a 2.5k plugin really given the requirement, even if you have to add custom code to match your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the fastest way is to inject the html into an hidden iFrame and print it's content.

Comment: I believe that is what the jQPrint plugin does.

Comment: Exactly! This is what jqPrint is doing as well!